# How to fill a symbolLayer with a custom texture?

Tags: qgis, c++, feature-class, function

I have this code :

```
pLayer is a QgsVectorLayer *

QgsFeatureRendererV2 * lrenderer = pLayer->rendererV2();
QList<QgsSymbolV2 *> lSymbols = lrenderer->symbols();
QgsSymbolLayerV2 * MySymbolLayer = lSymbols.at(0)->symbolLayer(0);
MySymbolLayer->setColor( QColor(90,90,90));
MySymbolLayer->setFillColor(QColor(90,90,90));
```

but how can I use the SetCustomTexture or setLineStyle from the 1.8 QGIS
Version , I want to fill the fill polygon with a specific texture or to define a type of line like DashLine

but I don't find the way to do it in C++ API  Qgis 2.8.2 for my application.

Comment: Perhaps the documentation for [QGIS 2.8 styling via PyQGIS](http://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/vector.html#appearance-symbology-of-vector-layers) might help?